# Pressing the button only changing the button, not the frames

Tags: python, tkinter

Making a simple GUI but whenever I press the page button nothing happens. But if I comment out those buttons everything works.
The game class is the main frame containing two small frames in it.The buttons inside the window works but the ones inside the frame doesn't

I have marked the ploblem line.

```
import tkinter as tk

class game:
    def __init__(self):
    self.window=tk.Tk()
    self.window.title('Market')
    self.window.geometry('800x600+0+0')

    container=tk.Frame(self.window,height=300,width=600,bg='red')
    container.place(x=0,y=0)

    f1=page1(container,self)
    f2=page2(container,self)

    self.frames={'page1':f1,'page2':f2}

    b1=tk.Button(self.window,text='page1',command= lambda : self.show_frame('page1'))
    b1.pack(side='right')

    b2=tk.Button(self.window,text='page2',command= lambda : self.show_frame('page2'))
    b2.pack(side='right')

    self.window.mainloop()

def show_frame(self,page_name):
    framz=self.frames[page_name]
    framz.frame.tkraise()
    
class page1:
    def __init__(self,root,parent):
        self.frame=tk.Frame(root,width=600,height=300,bg='blue')
        self.frame.place(x=0,y=0)
        
        #problem lies here
        b2=tk.Button(self.frame,text='page2',command= lambda : game.show_frame(parent,'page2'))
        b2.pack(side='right')

class page2:
    def __init__(self,root,parent):
        self.frame=tk.Frame(root,width=600,height=300,bg='green')
        self.frame.place(x=0,y=0)

        #problem lies here
        b1=tk.Button(self.frame,text='page1',command= lambda : game.show_frame(parent,'page1'))
        b1.pack(side='right')

app=game()
```

Comment: Your code works fine.  Just the two frames (`page1` and `page2`) are shrink to the size of the button.  You can add `relwidth` and `relheight` options like `self.frame.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)` to expand the frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for that is that you should just put the height and width of the frames (page1 and page2) [by using the options relwidth and relheight]

so a replacement code for that is:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window=tk.Tk()
        self.window.title('Market')
        self.window.geometry('800x600+0+0')

        container = tk.Frame(self.window,height=300,width=600,bg='red')
        container.place(x=0,y=0)

        f1=page1(container,self)
        f2=page2(container,self)
    
        self.frames={'page1':f1,'page2':f2}
    
        b1=tk.Button(self.window,text='page1',command= lambda : self.show_frame('page1'))
        b1.pack(side='right')
    
        b2=tk.Button(self.window,text='page2',command= lambda : self.show_frame('page2'))
        b2.pack(side='right')
    
        self.window.mainloop()

    def show_frame(self,page_name):
        global framz
        framz = self.frames[page_name]
        framz.frame.tkraise()
    
class page1:
    def __init__(self,root,parent):
        self.frame=tk.Frame(root,width=600,height=300,bg='blue')
        self.frame.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)
        
        #problem lies here
        b2=tk.Button(self.frame,text='page2',command= lambda : game.show_frame(parent,'page2'))
        b2.pack(side='right')

class page2:
    def __init__(self,root,parent):
        self.frame=tk.Frame(root,width=600,height=300,bg='green')
        self.frame.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)
        #problem lies here
        b1=tk.Button(self.frame,text='page1',command= lambda : game.show_frame(parent,'page1'))
        b1.pack(side='right')

app = game()
```

Comment: `relwidth=10` should be `relwidth=1`.  Same for `relheight`.

Comment: Okay! i have changed it